# DOM Events on ajax unloadable content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What is the right way to handle events in relation to ajax loadable/unload-able content?

I have a sidebar in HTML that gets hidden and display on click. And two pages loadable through ajax.

When the sidebar is hidden/displayed, I need to call resize methods in one of the ajax loaded page. The other page does not have that need.

```
$('body').on('click', '.show-sidebar', function (e) {
        //.. invoke some page1 resize methods here, only if page1 is present
    });
```

The question is: Is there anyway, I can have the above handler live only for the duration of the page1 and go away (undefined/nullified) once the page is unloaded?

Or even better, instead of defining the event handler on 'body', is there a way the handlers can be defined on page1 dom elements (so that they listen to *any* .side-bar click event anywhere)??

Comment: You could namespace your events, eg `.on('click.page1', fn)`. Then when you want to remove any event handler related to `page1` you simply call `.off('.page1');`. See the 'Events and namespaces' section for more detail: https://api.jquery.com/on/ https://api.jquery.com/off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, Rory is right on this one. You could use a conditional to detect the `.length` of an object on each of the pages to then delegate your events.

```
$('body').on('click', '.show-sidebar', function (e) {
    if( $('#page1').length > -1 ){
        $('body').on('resize', '#your-selector', function(){
            // Do your thing
        });
    } else {
        $('body').off('resize', '#your-selector');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if I didn't understand the question correctly.